# javascript change image, href onclick = looking for simpliest method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What is the simpliest method to change image src, when I click on a href -with JQuery?

`img id="my_image" class="icon" src="1.png" alt="1.png" border="0" />

< a href="#" id="1">

< a href="#" id="2">

< a href="#" id="3">`


1.png, 2.png, 3.png

Href is OK with # or would be better to placce here some JS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should `.bind()`<sup>[help](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)</sup> a `.click()`<sup>[help](http://api.jquery.com/click/)</sup> event listener on your anchors. In that listener, you change the **src** attribute by invoking `.attr()`<sup>[help](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)</sup>

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
    $('#my_image').attr('src', function(i, src) {
        return event.target.id + '.png';
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: $('#my_image').attr('src', event.target.id + '.png') would seem easier.

Comment: Thank you, working. But what If I have other hrefs on that page (not for image changing)? In this case other href change image too, ehich is not good.

Comment: @Adrian: indeed, you should give those anchors that **should** change your image a unique classname, for instance "changeimage". Then specifically only bind the event to those anchors by calling `$('a.changeimage').click(function(event) { ...`

Comment: I am deciding between you and Prisoner's method. With your method I still can use transitions, but Prisoner's alternative is a bit simplier without jQuery.

Comment: jAndy, one problem left: the images are in my case charts, which are generated every 5 min. If am clicking on hrefs, they are load-change images perfectly, but not the fresh-latest images. I need to reload whole page to load new charts. <meta no cache not helped.

Comment: return 'cccam'+ event.target.id + '.png?' + Math.floor(Math.random()*9999999); Helped, thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
<img id="my_image" class="icon" src="1.png" alt="1.png" border="0" />
<a onclick="changeImage(this)" href="#" id="1">1</a>
<a onclick="changeImage(this)" href="#" id="2">2</a>
<a onclick="changeImage(this)" href="#" id="3">3</a>

<script>
function changeImage(thisDiv){
  document.getElementById('my_image').src = thisDiv.id+".png"
}
</script>
```

Edit: Didn't see the jQuery requirement!

Comment: I still think this is a useful answer to the question though. This site is as much about providing useful searchable answers as directly answering the specific question and this isn't an unreasonable way to achieve what the question wants to achieve.

Comment: Only 2 question left: what I need to change to work for other file names? adrian1.png, adrian2.png..  I wanted to use jQuery, because of transition effects. This can not be done with this method? If not, not a big deal.. :)

Comment: If you wish to use jQuery then I would go with jAndy's solution (with adding a class to each anchor you wish to make clickable). This way you dont have a mess of normal javascript and jquery.

Answer (score 2):

This ought to work:

```
<a href="javascript:$('#my_image').attr('src', '2.png');" id="1">
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    var id = this.id;
    $('#my_image').attr('src', id + '.png');
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```